# PHP: Can range() be used for fractions?

Tags: php, decimal, range, fractions

Could it be possible to use the range() function in PHP to generate a list of fractions or decimals?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah, if you specify the step (third parameter). This parameter is only available in PHP 5, but you should be using that by now anyway.

For example, to generate decimals between 0 and 1, inclusive, in intervals of 0.1:

```
print_r(range(0, 1, 0.1));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 0.1
    [2] => 0.2
    [3] => 0.3
    [4] => 0.4
    [5] => 0.5
    [6] => 0.6
    [7] => 0.7
    [8] => 0.8
    [9] => 0.9
    [10] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's broken for me now on PHP 7.0.10, probably due to rounding issues depending on the range boundaries.

It works for the range `0.1..0.9`:

```
print_r(range(0.1, 0.9, 0.1));
Array
(
    [0] => 0.1
    [1] => 0.2
    [2] => 0.3
    [3] => 0.4
    [4] => 0.5
    [5] => 0.6
    [6] => 0.7
    [7] => 0.8
    [8] => 0.9
)
```

Bit it is broken for the range `0.2..0.9`, for instance (`0.9` is missing):

```
print_r(range(0.2, 0.9, 0.1));
Array
(
    [0] => 0.2
    [1] => 0.3
    [2] => 0.4
    [3] => 0.5
    [4] => 0.6
    [5] => 0.7
    [6] => 0.8
)
```